# Default friendly url for page

Tags: liferay, portlet, friendly-url

I am using Liferay 5.2.9. I have my own class ViewFriendlyUrlMapper which extends BaseFriendlyURLMapper. I overwrote buildPath and populateParams methods. Everything is working fine, but I have one, small problem.

I have main page with address: host/web/quest/myPage, on which I put portlet, showing some text from database. When I would like to show text with name "super-text" friendlyUrlMapper generates url like this: /web/quest/myPage/-/text/super-text. In portlet configuration I have options: name of defualt text, which is takken when url has no parameters (/web/quest/myPage).

My question is: is there any way to redirect url with no parameters (/web/quest/myPage) to url with name of default text from portlet preferences?

Comment: Did you go through http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper

Comment: Yes, I didn't find the solution.